# Text to dictionary and print multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file like this:

```
key1: value1 value2 value 3
key2: value1 value2 value 3
key3: value1 value2 value 3
```

I am trying to open it as a dictionary and print the list of keys and values so it looks like this in the end:

```
key1 value1
key1 value2
key1 value3
key2 value1
key2 value2
key2 value3
```

I am trying the following code:

```
f = open('groups_4.txt', 'r')
answer = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    print(k+'\t'+'\n{0}\t'.format(k).join(v))
f.close()
```

However it gives me an output like this:

```
key1 v
key1 a
key1 l
key1 u …
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Comment: `.join(v)` iterates over each character in e.g. `"value1"` separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that it:

```
f = open('groups_4.txt', 'r')
answer = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    answer[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    for word in v.split():
        print k, word

f.close()
```

That loop with word iterate over the line "v", what is "value1 value2 value3" splitted by whitespaces. Word is element of that line.

Comment: yes it is, thanks a lot, I tried so long to do that by myself! Can you explain me what "word" stands for in that case? and what's the difference (apart from the obvious) from my code? I want to understand and learn. THanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Do not use `print` anymore, but `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('group_4.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    value=v.split(' ')
    answer={}
    for v in value:
        answer[k] = v
        print answer
f.close()
```

In v you get value1 value2 value3 so split it.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

```
f = open('groups_4.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    key, valuetext = line.split(': ')
    for value in valuetext.split():
        print('{} {}'.format(key,value))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

f = open('1.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    value=v.split(' ')
    answer={}
    for v in value:
        answer[k] = v
        print answer

f.close()